# EF Core DataAnnotations not used in Razor page

Tags: razor, data-annotations, ef-core-7.0, metadatatype

I am using `Html.LabelFor` in my razor page.

The auto generated EF entities I have are:

```
public partial class Projectinformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

   // [Display(Name = "Project Number")] <--- this works but
   // gets overwritten if database changes
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

If I add the DisplayAtribute here it works.  However, I want to use an extension outside of the autogenerated code and found this pattern in the MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name?view=net-7.0):

```
public class ProjectMetaData
{
    [Display(Name = "Project Number")] //<--- This does not work
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ProjectMetaData))]
public partial class Projectinformation
{
}
```

But this does not work (I get `Code` as the label rather than `Project Number`).  Everything is in the `Project.Models` namespace.  The linked documentation has the metadata class inside the partial class, which I also tried but same result.

Here is  the razor code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

And here is the resulting html:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Code">Code</label>
```

What am I missing?